# Routes are giving me the hardest time right now

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink, routes

I'm working through a ton of ruby tutorials right now, and am having the hardest time figuring out the whole Routes thing.
For instance, I mostly understand the paperclip file upload,  but what I'm getting hung up on is the way the images are displayed.  I know the problem is in the way the Routes are being routed, but can't quite grasp the exact syntax.  Perhaps someone can help explain this to me.

Example:
This is the code for one of my thumbnails:

```
<% for photo in @user.photos %>
<%= link_to image_tag(photo.photo.url(:small)), photo.photo.url(:standard)%>
<% end %>
```

and the link that is delivered is:

localhost:3000/system/photos/29/standard/8.png?1306281491

So I know the timestamp is at the end of the url, but what I want is a link like this:

localhost:3000/users/1/photos/29

Help!  and thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake routes` command and you will see all routes defined in your application.

Among them, you will see something like:

```
 user_photo GET /users/:user_id/photo/:id(.:format) 
                {:action=>"show", :controller=>"photos"}
```

So, to get `/users/1/photos/29`, you need to call method
`user_photo_path(user_obj, photo_obj)`

I advise you to read [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: That's the problem - the photo is attached to the user, and not it's own model so there isn't a defined route for any photo objects